# This expression was expected to have type xxxx but here has type unit

Tags: f#

The following code has a type error for both of the `printfn`s.

How should I fix it? I'd like the `Seq.map` loop to continue even if one of the items fails.

```
// files should be a Seq of record 
let files = seqOfStrs |> Seq.map(fun s ->
    match s with
    | Helper.ParseRegex "(\w+) xxxxx" month ->
        let currentMonth =  .....
        if currentMonth = month.[0] then
            doc.Load(shelf)
            // parse doc and return record type. Omitted
        else
            printfn "Expect %s found %s." currentMonth month.[0] //Error
    | _ ->
        printfn "No '(Month) Payment Data On Line' prompt." //Error
```

Comment: BTW, your error message mentions strings, but you talk about actually producing 'record' values in the comments. Do you just mean records represented as strings, or do you actually want an F# record? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx

Comment: Eventually the code will return a record seq. Temporary I just return a string for testing. I should update the code for consistence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the different branches of your logic are producing different things. In the "omitted" section you're apparently returning a value of type xxxx (e.g. `string`), but in the other branches with the `printfn` calls, you're returning without a value, which in F# is represented as `unit` and in other languages is often called `void`.

If you didn't want the loop to continue, the simplest answer would be to just throw an exception in those cases, e.g:

```
failwithf "Expect %s found %s." currentMonth month.[0]
```

The static return type of [`failwithf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340261.aspx) can be any type at all, including `string`, because it never actually returns so doesn't actually have to produce a value of that type.

Given that you do want your code to continue, you could instead return an empty string or some kind of failure value, e.g.:

```
printfn "Expect %s found %s." currentMonth month.[0] //Error
"failed"
```

Now all the branches have the same type so your code will compile, but you have to be careful that callers don't accidentally interpret this value as being some valid result, which is why throwing an exception is generally cleaner.

A cleaner approach is to use an [`option`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233245.aspx) value to represent success or failure, i.e. return `Some "..."` in the correct case and `None` in the error cases. This approach is nicer when the failure is a common-place occurrence that the calling code would like to handle rather than just reporting the problem to the user and aborting:

```
// files should be a Seq of record 
let files = seqOfStrs |> Seq.map(fun s ->
    match s with
    | Helper.ParseRegex "(\w+) xxxxx" month ->
        let currentMonth =  .....
        if currentMonth = month.[0] then
            doc.Load(shelf)
            // parse doc and produce record type.
            Some record
        else
            printfn "Expect %s found %s." currentMonth month.[0] //Error
            None
    | _ ->
        printfn "No '(Month) Payment Data On Line' prompt." //Error
        None
```

You now need to decide what you want `files` to contain at that point - do you want the explicit `None` value to show that something failed, or do you just want the sequence to contain the correct values and omit the failures entirely?

If you want the explicit values, then you can just leave the `option` values in place and you'll have a `seq<string option>` result. Note that this type is just syntactic sugar for `seq<option<string>>`, reflecting F#'s O'Caml heritage.

If you just want to omit them, then replace your `Seq.map` call with [`Seq.choose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340250.aspx), which will drop all the `None` values and strip off the `Some` wrappers, leaving you with `seq<string>` as your current code is trying to produce.

Comment: Will `failwith` stop the loop? I just want the loop continue next item in these branches.

Comment: yes, it would. In that case I'd recommend the `option` approach I suggested at the end in my last edit. I'll elaborate a bit on how you might work with that.